# How do you use MSDeploy to sync a whole solution over http?

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I'm able to use MSDeploy to deploy one project at a time with the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 "Publish" wizard. I deploy over http.

My visual studio solution contains many projects and some depends on shared DLL. Is it possible to sync a whole solution?

My goal would be to fully automate deployment.

Carl

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use WDeploy directly from the command line? You can specify a manifest file, where you'd put all necessary components for deployment and then sync against manifest msdeploy provider:

```
Source manifest (Source.xml)
<MyDeployment>
        <appHostConfig path="MyLocalSiteName" />
<!-- 
     You can also use iisApp depending on what permissions you have on the remote server.
     If you have permissions execute appHostConfig that will create a site if the site does not exist.
 -->
        <iisApp path="MyLocalSiteName\MyApp" />

        <dirPath path="C:\Solution\Project1" />
        <dirPath path="C:\Solution\Project2" />
        <gacAssembly path="My.GACed.Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1111111111'" />
</MyDeployment>


Destination manifest (Destination.xml)
<MyDeployment>
        <appHostConfig path="MyRemoteSiteName" />
        <iisApp path="MyRemoteSiteName\MyApp" />

        <dirPath path="\\RemoteServerShare\Solution\Project1" />
        <dirPath path="\\RemoteServerShare\Solution\Project2" />
        <gacAssembly path="My.GACed.Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1111111111'" />
</MyDeployment>
```

And the command line would be:

`msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:manifest=Source.xml -dest:manifest=Destination.xml,computername=MyServer`

... to go against MSDeploy agent, or

`msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:manifest=Source.xml -dest:manifest=Destination.xml,wmsvc=MyServer,username=User2,password=4321,authtype=basic`

... to against WMSvc.

[This blog post](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/423/using-custom-manifests/) can get you started on the manifest provider and [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569001%28WS.10%29.aspx) can explain some useful provider settings.